# chrome.storage.local.get causes exception

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to save pair pageUrl:imageUrl into chrom local storage. Here is the code:

```
    function saveImage (href, urlImage)
    {
        var dataObj = {href:urlImage};
        dataObj[href] = urlImage;
        chrome.storage.local.set(dataObj);
        console.log("Image url has been saved into storage "+href);

    }

    function tryLoadCachedImageUrl(hrefObj)
    {
        console.log("Trying to load image from storage: "+hrefObj.href);
        chrome.storage.local.get(hrefObj.href, 
        function(result){   
                loadImages(result,hrefObj);
        });

    }
```

chrome.storage.local.get causes exception:

> Error in response to storage.get: ReferenceError: obj is not defined

hrefObj.href contains string, equal to `pageUrl` which was saved in `saveImage`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is probably in `loadImages`. How is it defined ? What does `obj` refer to ? (Did you change the variable names before posting the code here ?)

Comment: Try `chrome.storage.local.get("href", 
        function(result){   
                loadImages(result,hrefObj);
        });` and see if it works

Comment: But he doesn't want to get `"href"`. He wants `hrefObj.href`. (`"href"` will probably return the last image saved because of OP's wrong initialization of the stored object, but this does not solve the overall problem in any case.)

Comment: Yep, you were right, ExpertSystem. Problem was in undefined `obj` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*For anyone landing on this page facing a similar situation*]

The error is in `loadImages`. It seems to be trying to access an undefined `obj` variable.

---

BTW, this line of code: `var dataObj = {href:urlImage};`
is **not** equivalent to: `dataObj[href] = urlImage;`
but to: `dataObj["href"] = urlImage;` (which is clearly not what you want)

The intended way is:

```
var dataObj = {};   // <-- create an empty object
dataObj[href] = urlImage;   // <-- the value of the `href` variable
                            //     is used as the key (not the string "href")
```

[***Note**: This is not causing the problem, it is just bad practice - if nothing else it "hurts" code clarity.*]